# how to Save a bool to show its value after the application re-opens in Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a core data that saves parsed feed and stores it. It then shows that feed and i have a button in every table view cell that bookmarks the cell to show it even if the application is offline.

this is the code for the button.

```
- (void)clickedButton:(UIButton*)sender {

    NSLog(@"Row: %d", sender.tag);

    NSIndexPath* indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:0];
    Stories *story = (Stories *)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    BOOL isSaved = [story.isBookmarked boolValue];
    story.isBookmarked = [NSNumber numberWithBool:!isSaved];


    [self.tableView reloadData];
```

my question is : 
how do i save the bool value to show even when the application restarts.

Answer (score 0):

you can use NSUserDefaults.
With this code you save your value

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool: forKey: ];

Using this approach, you can even make your own value appears in iOS device setting.
Just add Setting.bundle and define what you want.

Other way is to use NSCoding protocol. It is simpler but no end user can see your stored values.